# How to pass correctly parameters with navigation service from a viewmodel to another?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

i'm trying to pass parameters from a viewmodel to another, how is described here: 
https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin.forms-navigation-with-mvvm-light.
The problem is that when i call my `NavigateAsync(string pageKey, object parameter, bool animated = true)` , it's thrown a `InvalidOperationException` and the message setted in the navigation service is: `No suitable constructor found for page`.

My actual code is the following:

The page I want to navigate to:

```
     public partial class FullScreenImagePopupPage : PopupPage
     {
       public FullScreenImagePopupPage(ImageSource imageSource)
       {
          var vm = App.Locator.FullScreenImageVM;
         BindingContext = vm;
         InitializeComponent();

         if (imageSource != null)
            vm.ImageSourceFullscreen = imageSource;
        }
      }
```

it's viewmodel:

```
     public class FullScreenImageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ImageSource _ImageSourceFullscreen { get; set; }

    public ImageSource ImageSourceFullscreen
    {
        get { return _ImageSourceFullscreen; }
        set
        {
            _ImageSourceFullscreen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public FullScreenImageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {

    }
}
```

The command called everytime i want to navigate to FullScreenImagePopupPage:
`OpenFullImageCommand = new Command(async () =>await navigationService.NavigateAsync(Locator.FullScreenImagePopupPage, ImageSourceFullScreen));`

The `NavigateAsync` function's implementation:

```
     public async Task NavigateAsync(string pageKey, object parameter, bool animated = true)
    {
        var page = GetPage(pageKey, parameter);


        if (page is PopupPage)
            await CurrentNavigationPage.Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page as PopupPage, true);
        else
        {
            await CurrentNavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page, animated);
        }
    }

    public Page GetPage(string pageKey, object parameter = null)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (!_pagesByKey.ContainsKey(pageKey))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"No such page: {pageKey}. Did you forget to call NavigationService.Configure?");
            }

            var type = _pagesByKey[pageKey];
            ConstructorInfo constructor;
            object[] parameters;

            if (parameter == null)
            {
                constructor = type.GetTypeInfo()
                    .DeclaredConstructors
                    .FirstOrDefault(c => !c.GetParameters().Any());

                parameters = new object[]
                {
                };
            }
            else
            {
                var a = type.GetTypeInfo()
                    .DeclaredConstructors;

                constructor = type.GetTypeInfo()
                    .DeclaredConstructors
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                        c =>
                        {
                            var p = c.GetParameters();
                            return p.Length == 1
                                   && p[0].ParameterType == parameter.GetType();
                        });

                parameters = new[]
                {
                parameter
            };
            }

            if (constructor == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "No suitable constructor found for page " + pageKey);
            }

            var page = constructor.Invoke(parameters) as Page;
            return page;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you debug to see if the constructor is null ?

Comment: Yeah, i did and the constructor actually is null, but still i don't have any idea how to resolve the problem. @LeoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I suggest you modify on the basis of sample.The above code looks fine

Comment: I used your code to modify parts of the sample, and it worked

Comment: Ok, i think i found the problem. There is a mismatching between the imageSource in the constructor and the parameter that i pass when i call the navigation function.This parameter is seen as ImageStreamSource, so the navigation service doesn't found the right constructor.